# Redirect header

Tags: php

I have an email form, that i'm validating a date, its a booking form. What im doing is when the start date is bigger than the end date it gives me a message saying to fix the date and redirect to the page. I have 2 pages, the page of the booking form, and when i click to submit it goes to the contact_engine page to validate and send the email:

here is how i put it:

```
if ($datebegin >= $dateend){
    echo '<script>alert("Fix the Date");</script>'; 

exit;
```

The problem is when it does the exit it stays in the functions page, and i want it to exit but go to the previous page. Can someone give me some help? I tried instead using `exit`. I try to use it with `header("Refresh: 1; url=http:/website.com/booking.php");` but somehow this takes me to the to the `sent_page_booking page`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest an alternative approach: the correct way to handle form submission with validation is to use the **Post-Redirect-Get** technique:

1. User submits the form (that is the **POST** request).
2. Is the form valid? If so, process it and **redirect** to the confirmation page with **GET**.
3. If the form isn't valid, just display the form with error messages (as a response to the original **POST** request.

To illustrate:

```
+--------+   POST   +--------+   Yes    +----------+   GET   +--------------+
| Submit | -------> | Valid? | -------> | Redirect | ------> | Confirmation |
+--------+          +--------+          +----------+         +--------------+
     ^                   |
     |                   | No
     +-------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
header("Location: phppage.php");
```

and do not use `echo` before this code. Put this code in starting and call it with button event.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing a timed redirect, so that the user gets the error message shown:

```
header("refresh:5;url=back-to-booking-form.php");
echo 'Form Error. Fix the date. Redirecting to the booking form in about 5 secs.';
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this Below link to exact answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539752/redirect-function

```
function redirect_url($path)
{
  header("location:".$path);
  exit;
}
```